# Do I have to take science in high school to become a pilot?

Tags: pilots, career

Some articles say we don’t need to take science in high school to become a pilot but some say we do... It’s very confusing and I don’t know which subject to take; Science, commerce or arts.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Which country are you living in?

Comment: Just consider whether arts or commerce are going to help you as a pilot. Science is: modern airliners, should you reach that level, are some of the most complex machines ever built, and the way their flight dynamics behave is not intuitive at all. Flying involves a lot of math and physics.

Comment: If you wanna fly highly profitably or very beautifully, commerce or arts will be of help. Otherwise, take science.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! This is a good question but a lot depends on the country you're in, can you edit your question to add that? And can we assume that you want to be an airline pilot? You might find [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32778/62) is helpful.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by wanting to become a pilot.  There's a lot of possibilities, ranging from ones where you get paid, such as airline pilots, bush pilots, crop dusters, or various types of military pilots, or just getting a pilot's license and flying your own plane.  For the latter, science is perhaps the better choice, since it gives you a better chance of having sufficient disposable income :-)

Comment: My kids had to take at least 3 years of science in high school just to graduate.

Answer (score 6):

There are no specific high school or college academic requirements specified for pilots in the U.S. Code of Federal Regulations.

However, basic knowledge in math and the physical sciences is important, and will greatly improve your understanding of subjects that are taught in ground school so that you can successfully pass required written and oral exams.

Furthermore, to be competitive as a professional pilot a college degree definitely helps, and you will likely need some minimum science credits both to get in, and to graduate.  Don't skimp on your education!

Comment: Agree. The earlier you start on science, the easier it will be later on when it gets progressively more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to take science? No, possibly not. Should you? Absolutely yes!

Without a basic understanding of science, it will be very difficult to understand the basics of flight as they are all about the balancing of forces (which is physics). Fuel management, air density and atmospherics are easier with a knowledge of physics and chemistry and navigation makes use of physics and mathematics. You could certainly get your private pilots license without any science though navigation will give you problems, but it is very unlikely that you could get a commercial license without a broader education.